# Unable to get gzip working with code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

### enable compression / Enable Gzip

I am using **code igniter** from three to four months. I heared some where gzip is a good technique to reduce size of page and also good with SEO but i have a problem now. So Probelm is that when i enable it from config, i ***cant see my auto sugges***t working, i heared i have to use **JSON** as i am not using that, is there any other solution?
i have installed firubug, so it starts giving errors as i enter in auto suggest.

Comment: Could you provide ud with the errors firebug is giving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use echo?, Try
    $this->output->set_output($json);